# Grep regex command

Tags: grep, sh

I currently have,

```
grep -G <a href="machines.jsp\?type=active>.<\/a>
```

and this matches the string I am looking for

```
<a href="machines.jsp\?type=active>4<\/a>
```

but I am not getting any output. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Well, Silly mistake. I missed the `"` to complete the href

Comment: How do you know this matches your string without output from grep?

Comment: Tested online. http://regexr.com/3bjdh

Comment: @KKa those regexp testing web sites are extremely misleading. Every flavor of every tool has it's own regexps and/or caveats - there is no one "regexp" and so there is no way for a site to be able to tell you if a regexp will work or not in whatever tool you plan to use it. Post some sample input and expected output so we can help you as we can't tell from a script that doesn't do what you want what it is you actually do want.

Comment: There are lots of characters in that regex that have special meaning to the shell. You need to quote it. `grep -G '<a ...'`